# how to create a customer by using two fields passwords and confirm password in email section on magento2 checkout?

Tags: checkout, event-observer, login, code

I have two fields created at the email section in checkout in magento2. I want to create a customer on order place. I am currently using "sales_order_payment_save_before" to get field data but not getting any data from the field.

I have created two fields in email.html in

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/email.html

```
<!-- ko ifnot: isCustomerLoggedIn() -->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-login-form') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<form class="form form-login" data-role="email-with-possible-login"
      data-bind="submit:login"
      method="post">
    <fieldset id="customer-email-fieldset" class="fieldset" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label" for="customer-email"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span></label>
            <div class="control _with-tooltip">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="email"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: email,
                            hasFocus: emailFocused,
                            afterRender: emailHasChanged,
                            mageInit: {'mage/trim-input':{}}"
                       name="username"
                        placeholder="Please Enter Your Email"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                       id="customer-email" />
                <!-- ko template: 'ui/form/element/helper/tooltip' --><!-- /ko -->
                <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account after checkout.'--><!-- /ko --></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!--Hidden fields -->
    <fieldset class="fieldset hidden-fields" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label" for="customer-password"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text" data-bind=" attr: { placeholder: $t('Password'), }" type="password" name="password" id="customer-password" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off"/>
                <span class="note" data-bind="i18n: 'You already have an account with us. Sign in or continue as guest.'"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action login primary" data-action="checkout-method-login"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Login'"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary">
                <a class="action remind" data-bind="attr: { href: forgotPasswordUrl }">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Forgot Your Password?'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!--Hidden fields -->


    <!--Hidden fields -->
    <fieldset class="fieldset hidden-fields" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordNotVisible">
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label" for="guest-customer-password"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text" data-bind=" attr: { placeholder: $t('Password'), }" type="password" name="password" id="guest-customer-password" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <label class="label" for="guest-customer-confirm-password"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Confirm Password'"></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input-text" data-bind=" attr: { placeholder: $t('Confirm Password'), }" type="password" name="password" id="guest-customer-confirm-password" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off"/>
                <span class="note" data-bind="i18n: 'If you want to create an account then click on create account button.'"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>
    <!--Hidden fields -->
</fieldset>
```

And I am using this event to retrieve data  created at :
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<event name="sales_order_payment_save_before">
    <observer name="event_for_sign_up_on_order" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\UserSignup" />
</event>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event `sales_order_payment_save_before` only takes hold of payment information (payment method, paid amount, credit card information,...). While the data (email and passwords) you need is stored inside the quote payload, that is why you did not see it such event.

To make this happen, we will need to do something more complex:

The rough idea here is, we want to create a new customer account (only) upon order success. But after placing order successfully, all quote data not being saved is lost. So our method is to save the data we need somewhere else first, then later create a new account once order is placed.

0. Ensure your UI component is all correct.
1. Populate an API endpoint to retrieve and store the data needed to create an account (i.e. email and passwords) in checkout session.

`etc/webapi.xml`

```xml
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/customer-information" method="POST">
    <service class="Foo\Bar\Api\GuestCheckoutManagementInterface" method="saveCustomerInformation"/>
    <resources>
      <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

`Model/GuestCheckoutManagement.php`

```php
class GuestCheckoutManagement implements GuestCheckoutManagementInterface
{
    public function saveCustomerInformation($cartId, ...more params) {
        // save the data you need to checkout session
    }
}
```

2. Call the API endpoint we just populated anywhere before placing order.

For example, create a mixin for this component: `Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default` and override `placeOrder` function:

`view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default-mixin.js`

```javascript
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        placeOrder: function (data, event) {
            // call the API

            // execute the original function
            this._super(data, event);
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

3. Create an observer for the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`.

`etc/events.xml`

```xml
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
    <observer name="create_customer_upon_order_success" instance="Foo\Bar\Observer\CreateCustomerUponOrderSuccess" />
</event>
```

`Observer/CreateCustomerUponOrderSuccess.php`

```php
class CreateCustomerUponOrderSuccess extends ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // get the saved data from checkout session
        // then
        // create a new account from that data
        // also, remember to log them in as a new created account
    }
}
```

Sorry for not being able to provide the detailed solution and working code, but this solution is what I learned from my past experience, which should help you somehow.

If you need further assistance, let me know.

Happy coding!